# UICollectionView Bug When Top Subview in "Structure" Pane

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, interface-builder

After banging my head against all the walls of the building, I have noticed that whenever I have a `UICollectionView` as a subview of my view controller's main view, the following holds:

If the collection view is the first subview in the "Structure" pane in Interface builder, the cells are pushed down by about 128 points (see images below:)

[image: Interface Builder view stack]

(red background is collection view)

[image: iPad screenshot]

However, if I add another view above the collection view, the item cells line up at the top (as expected), no extraneous margin:

[image: Interface Builder view stack (2)]
[image]

...but it has to be placed **above** the collection view: If I re-arrange the views and place the dummy **below** the collection view, the bug resurfaces.

This collection view is horizontal scroll, one line (section). Ideally, the collection view height is the same as the cell height (no margin), so the bug caused the cells to not show at all. I had to try and enlarge the the collection view's canvas vertically to finally realize what was going on.

Is this a documented feature I am somehow missing, or is it a bug?

I fell like naming my dummy view "spacer.gif" and enjoying some late-nineties nostalgia.

**ADDENDUM:** I have further investigated and discovered that, the dummy view placed above the collection view is a necessary condition for it to work, but not sufficient. Moving it around (mostly to hide it) or adding/changing constraints on it makes the bug resurface in some cases. Very annoying, can't quite figure out the exact conditions...

Comment: You are not alone,I have met this bug,too.I have no choice but to add `UICollectionView` by code instead of doing this in xib.